# Use of nested transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

I thought that nested transaction is used to take transactions apart as below.

```rb
User.transaction do
  User.create(username: 'Kotori')
  User.transaction do
    User.create(username: 'Nemu')
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

But the code will generate both `Kotori` and `Nemu`.
To get `Kotory` only, it should be below.

```rb
User.transaction do
  User.create(username: 'Kotori')
  User.transaction(requires_new: true) do
    User.create(username: 'Nemu')
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

But why is that? Why we need to use `requires_new` option explicitly? Is there any use case for `requires_new: false` ?

Thanks

reference : [https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#:~:text=ActiveRecord%3A%3AStatementInvalid%20occurred.-,Nested%20transactions,-transaction%20calls%20can](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#:%7E:text=ActiveRecord%3A%3AStatementInvalid%20occurred.-,Nested%20transactions,-transaction%20calls%20can)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested transactions work this way because *nested transaction block become part of the parent transaction*. It is implemented this way because *most databases don't support true nested transactions*.

And because it depends on the used database system if nested transactions are supported or not, Ruby on Rails cannot make the less surprising option the default behavior.

This is explained in the [docs about nested transactions in Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-Nested+transactions):

> **Nested transactions**
>
> `transaction` calls can be nested. By default, this makes all database statements in the nested transaction block become part of the parent transaction. For example, the following behavior may be surprising:
>
> ```
> User.transaction do
>   User.create(username: 'Kotori')
>   User.transaction do
>     User.create(username: 'Nemu')
>     raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> creates both “Kotori” and “Nemu”. Reason is the `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exception in the nested block does not issue a ROLLBACK. Since these exceptions are captured in transaction blocks, the parent block does not see it and the real transaction is committed.
>
> In order to get a ROLLBACK for the nested transaction you may ask for a real sub-transaction by passing `requires_new: true`. If anything goes wrong, the database rolls back to the beginning of the sub-transaction without rolling back the parent transaction. If we add it to the previous example:
>
> ```
> User.transaction do
>   User.create(username: 'Kotori')
>   User.transaction(requires_new: true) do
>     User.create(username: 'Nemu')
>     raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> only “Kotori” is created.
>
> Most databases don't support true nested transactions. At the time of writing, the only database that we're aware of that supports true nested transactions, is MS-SQL. Because of this, Active Record emulates nested transactions by using savepoints. See dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/savepoint.html for more information about savepoints.